# React/Redux - Add object to start of array using spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux

I am using a redux reducer to add objects to a state array. This is working correctly, however, the objects are being added to the end of the array. I have searched high and low, but cannot figure out how to use this syntax, not mutate the array and add the object to the start of an array.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

    case 'MOVIE_ADDED_TO_WATCHLIST':

            return [
                ...state,
                action.movie
            ];

        }

...****rest of the reducer here****.....
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to use the spread operator to add items to the beginning of an array, just use the spread operator after the new values. For example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let b = [0, ...a];

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Additionally, you can also use `.concat`:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var b = [0].concat(a);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

You can see a working example of this [here](https://es6console.com/iyzul71t/).